# TFS 2015 Code review feature - can't select reviewers

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-code-review

I'm using TFS 2015 with VS 2015 on a UWP project. On the team explorer, I can't select reviewers. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

NOTE: I have attached a screenshot for reference and you can see the textbox's placeholder text is not removing as well.

[image]

Comment: Can you enter the reviewers manually? Try to restart the VS, or clean the VS caches first, then restart it. If that still not work, just try to reset the user data with command `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`, then check that again.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: No. It still exist. Let’s wait and see. :)

Comment: Just try to run VS as administrator, then check that again.

Comment: We always runs VS on admin mode. Maybe it’s a permission issue. My investigation in this still not finished. I will update on this matter in couple of days.